# Write the data in the next row if the current row is not null

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am writing the calculation result to DataGridView in C#.

```
if( bool condition1)
{    
   form.myDataTable.Rows[j][cs] = "my string-1";
}

if( bool condition2)
{
  form.myDataTable.Rows[j][cs] = "my string-2";
}
.
.
.
j++
```

If condition 1 and condition 2 both are true string-2 is over written in place of string 1.
I can just do null check and write j=j+1 in block 2 so that it's written in a new row. But i have three more such bool check conditions. Please explain an elegant way to do this. I am newbie to C#. Thanks Bunch for help !!

Comment: *If condition 1 and condition 2 both are true string-2 is over written in place of string 1* Really? Because that's not what I understood `else if` to do.

Comment: Sorry, i am not supposed to have else in there. As i need both the values, if both conditions are true.

Comment: You're setting the value twice unnecessarily this way. If they both have to be true, you should use an and-condition.

Comment: It's not necessary that both are true. It depends on the input data values. Either one may be true or both may be false or both true.

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't each row on a new line:  The easiest thing would be to replace `j` with `j++`.

`j++` will return the value of `j` then increment it by one.

---

### In Response to First Comment

Would it be more useful to show:

```
my string-1
my string-2
```

Try

```
form.myDataTable.Rows[j][cs] += Environment.NewLine + "my string-2";
```

Comment: If i use J++ ,for example in the second bool condition i am using j like this: (price[j] < 101 && price[k] > 101). Which takes data from a different column. So my other column index points to a different row than what i want.

Comment: @user1783998 What output would you want?

Comment: I want the names as strings in one column and the corresponding values in another column. The Enviornment.newline is just attaching string1 to string 2 in the same row.